# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHex’) when trying to combine webgl_interactive_cubes with pointer lock three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, pointerlock

I’m trying to create scene with walk-navigation, with interactive objects, for educational purpose. I’m using [Pointer Lock Control example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=pointer#misc_controls_pointerlock) for a walk navigation and [interactive cubes example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=interactive#webgl_interactive_cubes) from three.js. It’s beginning so project is far from being perfect, although “walk” works. Unfortunately cursor part bugs out showing

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHex')
    at render (three-fps.js:200:62)
    at animate (three-fps.js:182:3)
```

this is my code:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { PointerLockControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/PointerLockControls.js";

let canvas;
let camera, scene, raycaster, renderer;

let INTERSECTED;
let controls;

let moveForward = false;
let moveBackward = false;
let moveLeft = false;
let moveRight = false;
let canJump = false;

let prevTime = performance.now();
const velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
const direction = new THREE.Vector3();

const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();
const radius = 100;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    70,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    10000
  );
  camera.position.y = 10;
  //controls
  controls = new PointerLockControls(camera, canvas);

  const onKeyDown = function (event) {
    switch (event.code) {
      case "ArrowUp":
      case "KeyW":
        moveForward = true;
        break;

      case "ArrowLeft":
      case "KeyA":
        moveLeft = true;
        break;

      case "ArrowDown":
      case "KeyS":
        moveBackward = true;
        break;

      case "ArrowRight":
      case "KeyD":
        moveRight = true;
        break;

      case "Space":
        if (canJump === true) velocity.y += 350;
        canJump = false;
        break;
    }
  };

  const onKeyUp = function (event) {
    switch (event.code) {
      case "ArrowUp":
      case "KeyW":
        moveForward = false;
        break;

      case "ArrowLeft":
      case "KeyA":
        moveLeft = false;
        break;

      case "ArrowDown":
      case "KeyS":
        moveBackward = false;
        break;

      case "ArrowRight":
      case "KeyD":
        moveRight = false;
        break;
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
  light.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
  scene.add(light);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);

  for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    const object = new THREE.Mesh(
      geometry,
      new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff })
    );

    object.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
    object.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
    object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

    object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

    object.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
    object.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
    object.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5;

    scene.add(object);
  }

  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  // floor

  let floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2000, 2000, 100, 100);
  floorGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

  const floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });

  const floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
  scene.add(floor);

  // Create a WebGL renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onPointerMove);

  //

  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function onPointerMove(event) {
  pointer.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  pointer.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}

//

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  const time = performance.now();
  const delta = (time - prevTime) / 1000;
  velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
  velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;
  direction.z = Number(moveForward) - Number(moveBackward);
  direction.x = Number(moveRight) - Number(moveLeft);
  direction.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions
  if (moveForward || moveBackward) velocity.z -= direction.z * 400.0 * delta;
  if (moveLeft || moveRight) velocity.x -= direction.x * 400.0 * delta;
  controls.moveRight(-velocity.x * delta);
  controls.moveForward(-velocity.z * delta);
  prevTime = time;
  camera.updateMatrixWorld();

  render();
}

function render() {
  camera.updateMatrixWorld();

  // find intersections

  raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);

  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, false);

  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    if (INTERSECTED != intersects[0].object) {
      if (INTERSECTED)
        INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);

      INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
      INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex();
      INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex(0xff0000);
    }
  } else {
    if (INTERSECTED)
      INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);

    INTERSECTED = null;
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex(); seems to be your issue. I would suggest some debugging to understand what the INTERSECTED and or INTERSECTED.material objects look like. your error indicates that "INTERSECTED.material.emissive" is undefined

Comment: maybe it’s worth mentioning that occasionally it works for a few seconds, but then error occur

Comment: I'm thinking that your intersected object does not have an emissive property on it's material. so, you can check for that before trying to reference it

Comment: This is not three.js related. Try logging and using `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// check for undefined 'emissive' on material
if (INTERSECTED.material.emissive != undefined) {
  INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex();
  INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex(0xff0000);
}
```